# How to use GroupBy within a nested join in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

The following SQL statement returns the username, IP address, duration, amount of traffic and last visit.

```
            SELECT username, SUBSTRING_INDEX( callingstationid, '=', 1 ) as IP,
                   SUM(acctsessiontime) as `duration`, count(username) as Count, 
                   (SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))/1000/1000/1000 as GBytes, 
                   MAX(acctstoptime) as `last visit`
            FROM radacct
            GROUP BY username
```

[image]

I would like to join this with the Country table, and group it by the country so that I know how much traffic each country has used and when was the last visit from that country.

I can't get the join right:

```
    SELECT  c.country, 
            round(GBytes, 2),  
            Count, 
            duration as `Total Time Spent`,
            `last visit`
            FROM (
                SELECT username, 
                       SUBSTRING_INDEX( callingstationid, '=', 1 ) as IP,        
                       SUM(acctsessiontime) as `duration`, count(username) as Count,                  
                       (SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))/1000/1000/1000 as GBytes,
                       MAX(acctstoptime) as `last visit`
                FROM radacct
                GROUP BY username
            ) filtered_radacct
            JOIN u_cache_db.`global_ip` c ON c.ip = filtered_radacct.IP
            GROUP BY c.country
            order by GBytes DESC;
```

I know that this numbers can't be right.

[image]

Comment: `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` tends to inflate the results.  Is that what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregation functions on all the fields in your top-level query as well i.e.

```
SELECT  c.country, 
        round(SUM(GBytes), 2),  
        SUM(Count), 
        SUM(duration) as `Total Time Spent`,
        MAX(`last visit`)
```

Comment: Darn, didn't see the wood for the trees. Thank you. You have a small mistake:         `SUM(round(GBytes, 2)), `

Comment: You are likely to get different results.  I vote for `ROUND(SUM(GBytes),2)`.

Comment: @RickJames indeed, that's why I do it in that order.